# Compare two strings and find mismatch count

Tags: c, string

I want to compare strings, each character with all other, whether they be in the same position or has an equal number in another position.

I don’t know how to use the compare of strings correctly, I tried with a `for` and `while` loop with a `count` but I don’t know.

My problem is this. For example.
My password is 1234.
My test is 1234.
In this case i have 4 deaths. Because the numbers are in the same position. But in this case.
My password is 1234.
My test is 1243.
I have 2 deaths because 1 and 2 are in correct position but 4 and 3 are in other position but they are in the other string. 
In this case i have 2 deaths and 2 injuries. 
Sorry for my english not very good . Thanks for help..

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO, Add the relevant part of your code (the comparison logic) here. Click edit, add the codes, state the problems that you are facing and what output you are getting. `Ctrl+k` will format the code part.

Comment: Your question is also not entirely clear. State your goal more clearly.

Comment: Please post actual code instead of screenshots. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Comment: `if(ret=0){` --> `if(ret==0){`

Comment: Thanks so much for answer my question. My problem is this. For example.
My password is 1234.
My test is 1234.
In this case i have 4 deaths. Because the numbers are in the same position. But in this case.
My password is 1234.
My test is 1243.
I have 2 deaths because 1 and 2 are in correct position but 4 and 3 are in other position but they are in the other string. 
In this case i have 2 deaths and 2 injuries. 
Sorry for my english not very good . Thanks for help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strcmp` will not give you the number of characters matching in the given strings. Try the below code, It will give number of matching characters in the input strings.

```
#include <string.h>

int GetMatchingChars (const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    int len1;
    int len2;
    int count = 0;
    int minLen = 0;
    char *shortPtr = NULL;
    char *longPtr = NULL;

    /* First check if the string are equal, return either len, no need to go further */
    if (strcmp (s1, s2) == 0) {
        return strlen(s1); /* or s2 */
    }

    len1 = strlen (s1);
    len2 = strlen (s2);
    minLen = (len1 <= len2)? len1:len2;
    shortPtr = (len1 <= len2)? s1:s2;
    longPtr =  (shortPtr == s1)? s2:s1;

    /* Loop through the shorter string */
    while (*shortPtr != '\0') {
        if (*shortPtr == *longPtr) {
            count++;
        }
        shortPtr++;  
        longPtr++;
    }

    return count;      
}

int main()
{
    char *s1 = "saac";
    char *s2 = "sbab";
    printf ("Matching len = %d\n", GetMatchingChars (s1,s2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have two strings like below:

```
 char *str1="Hai", *str2="Hai";
```

Use `strcmp(str1,str2)` for comparing two strings in **C**

**It will return**

```
0 => if str1==str2
>0 => if str1 > str2, which is lexicographically compared
<0 => if str1 < str2
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a point to above answer.
no need to use **for loop** while comparing, as strncmp takes the strings as input.
`strncmp` delcaration is 
`int strncmp(const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n);`